# Running header at center after the first page in article class

Tags: formatting, fancyhdr

Can I do this without explicitly putting in `\newpage` or a page break? Note that I also have sections in my article.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\markright{\hfill Running Header\hfill}
\section{test1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{test2}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{test3}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

**Note** Adding to the answer, if you want a specific text at the center: `\makeatletter\def\@oddhead{\hfil{\small\emph{Specific text}}\hfil}\makeatother`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter\def\@oddhead{\hfil{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil}\makeatother
\section{test1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{test2}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{test3}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This for some reason ignores the runnnig header to put the title of the section on every page

Comment: yes but the running header does not appear on the right hand side either.

Comment: I meant that the title does not appear at all. I edited the question.